# Altering table's unique field

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table which has an unique key with 2 constraints in it. I want to alter the table such that i can remove one of the constraint in unique field there.

**My current db schema :**

`CREATE TABLE testtable(test1 TEXT, test2 TEXT, test3 TEXT, test4 TEXT DEFAULT FALSE,UNIQUE (test1,test2))`

I already have this table populated with data and do not want to drop and recreate this table in my next release. Is there a way to alter the table's unique field. I did not set a constraint for my this table.

I want my database schema to be like this after update.

`CREATE TABLE testtable(test1 TEXT, test2 TEXT, test3 TEXT, test4 TEXT DEFAULT FALSE,UNIQUE (test1))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In other DBMSes you would have used `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT ...`. However sqlite only supports the `RENAME TABLE` and `ADD COLUMN` variants of the `ALTER TABLE` command ([Source](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html)).

Therefore, I'm afraid you'd have to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable2(
   test1 TEXT, test2 TEXT, test3 TEXT, test4 TEXT DEFAULT FALSE,
   UNIQUE (test1)
);
```

Then insert the data from the old table to the new table:

```
INSERT INTO testtable2 SELECT * FROM testtable;
```

Then you can drop the old table:

```
DROP TABLE testtable;
```

And finally rename the new table to the original name:

```
ALTER TABLE testtable2 RENAME TO testtable;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Be careful that your new constraint will be less permissive. For example if you had the following rows in your original table:

```
test1       test2       test3       test4     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
a           a           100         1         
a           b           200         2         
a           c           300         3
```

Then the `INSERT INTO testtable2 SELECT * FROM testtable;` would fail because `test1` is not unique:

```
SQL error: column test1 is not unique
```

Comment: I was about to take this approach of dropping and recreating the table and before doing that i just wanted to clarify whether there is any way to alter it...Thanks for the update Daniel :)

Comment: @Rahul: In your question you mentioned that you have 'two unique fields'. In reality, you have just one unique constraint, made up of two fields. Two unique fields would have meant `UNIQUE (test1), UNIQUE(test2)` in the table definition. I am not sure if you were aware of this, so I updated my answer with a note on this issue.

Comment: Yes i was wrong it was one unique constraint made up of two fields...I will update it